# How to toggle visibility of Asp.Net combobox with javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a set of server side combo boxes in a table. Based on client events, I need them to appear or disappear. I've tried the following with no success:

```
document.getElementById("cboToothNumber").style.visibility = "hidden"; 

$("#cboToothNumber").hide()
```

Any ideas? Also, this will need to work from a js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the ASP.NET ID, you want the client id, so try

```
$("#<%=cboToothNumber.ClientID%>").hide()
```

From a JS file, this won't work. You can use the same code to get the ClientID and set it as a variable or pass it into a function in the Javascript file though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ID of the combo boxes once the page has rendered? The Id of the element might be changing due to it being serverside.

If you are using .net 4 - there is a way to disable the ClientId by setting the ClientIdMode.

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="[Mode Type]" />
```

Check out these links:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: Could you post a snippet of what the rendered element looks like?

Comment: <select id="cboToothNumber" name="cboToothNumber">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
</select>

Comment: are you putting your $("#cboToothNumber").hide(); before or after the select element? Because it wont pick it up if you put it before - you will need to put the code after